# How to open camera with cv::VideoCapture in Android Native C++

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to use OpenCV v4.9.0 for Android to open a camera in Android Native C++, but got failure after trying different index and api combinations. When trying cv::CAP_ANDROID, I got this error

```
[ WARN:0@0.002] global cap.cpp:344 open VIDEOIO(ANDROID_NATIVE): backend is generally available but can't be used to capture by index
```

Not sure what caused the failure. The code is running on a rooted Android 13 device with SE disabled, so I guess it is not related to permissoin. Below is my code:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
int index = 0; //also tried 1, 32 and 33. The device has a camera module and can see video0, video1, video32 and video33 under/dev
int api = cv::CAP_ANDROID; //also tried cv::CAP_V4L2 and cv::CAP_ANY
cap.open(index, api);
if (!cap.isOpenend())
{
  //handle errors
}
```

Comment: what NDK version? are you *sure* this is opencv 4.9? see https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/19597/files

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, NDK is 26.1.10909125. For OpenCV, I am using the release version from OpenCV website https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/download/4.9.0/opencv-4.9.0-android-sdk.zip
I didn't build libopencv_java4.so from code, just using the prebuilt binaries. And from my code I can print the OpenCV version to confirm 4.9.0:

```
OpenCV version : 4.9.0
Major version : 4
Minor version : 9
Subminor version : 0
```

Comment: can you get anything out of `cv::getBuildInformation()`? what does it say about available video I/O backends? maybe build flags modulated the availability of this feature.

Comment: Sure, cv::getBuildInformation()' s output is quite lenthy, so I uploaded it as txt here https://ctxt.io/2/AAAI-mYwFw

I noticed this from the output,  this line "NDK Camera:  NO" seems suspicious, what do you think?

  Video I/O:
   MEDIANDK:                     YES
   NDK Camera:                   NO

Comment: hmmm I mean you could browse for issues on opencv's github about this. maybe it's been reported already, maybe not, so then you could file an issue. build information suggests that they used NDK 25 and the PR suggests 23 minimum for NDK camera. I don't know, just guessing. if you're up for it, you could build opencv yourself. then you have control over the build process, specifically any libraries it will depend on and any cmake variables that modulate it all.

Comment: I might need to comiple it from source. Do you happen to know how to build opencv for Android from source? It seems different from compiling it for Linux and I didn't find much info on this. Thanks!

Comment: that's beyond me. you could check the official OpenCV forum. there might be one or two people who might have dealt with this in the past. -- I see `build_sdk.py` [in here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.x/platforms/android) and I think I heard about that before. you might be able to find more on this in the forum or general internet

Comment: I found out how to build opencv from source for Android. It uses CMake and needs to define CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE as the full path of android.toolchain.cmake in NDK. Also needs to specify ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL and ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN in the command line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I figured out this issue might be due to lack of NDK Camera support in the prebuilt OpenCV 4.9.0 shared library for Android. I ended up building the lib from source and using it in my C++ code. Now `cap.open(0, cv::CAP_ANDROID);` returns OK. I ran into a different issue of `cap >> frame` always returns empty frames, which I am still looking at. But it is a progress from failing to open the camera.